# Primitive polynomials: some statements to (dis-)prove

Tags: abstract-algebra

> **Prove or disprove:**
>
> i) The sum of primitive polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is primitive
>
> ii) The product of primitive polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is primitive
>
> iii) There is only a finite number of primitive polynomials of degree $2$ in 
>   $\mathbb{Z}[x]$
>
> iv) There is only a finite number of primitive polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$

*i), ii)*

I'm not sure if I really understood the concept of primitive polynomials.

I think ii) can't be true, as it would (could) increase the degree of the polynomial, which therefore couldn't be minimal. i) might be still irreducible, but I have no clue of it is primitive or not, can you please explain this to me?

iii), iv)

Well, I am looking for irreducible polynomials that generate $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ respectively $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$. But how do I count them? Considering $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ there should be only a finite number of them, but how can this be proven (if it's right)?

Can you please help me by explaining why this statements do or don't apply?

Comment: There are different concepts of primitive polynomial. I assume in this context you mean: The polynomial has no non-unit constant factor? This would match ii) specifically, but then I have nbo idea why you keep bringing up irreducbility ...

Answer (score 3):

i) $1+2x$ and $2+x$ are primitive, their sum $3+3x$ is not.

ii) This follows from  Gauß' lemma

iii) $x^2+ax+b$ is primitive for arbitrary $a,b$

iv) Since there are no nonzero nonunits in $\mathbb F_2$, any nonzero polynomial in $\mathbb F_2[x]$ is primitive

Comment: thank you for your answer! Can you please explain the last one, iv), to me? Why is every nonzero polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ primitive, just because there are no nonzero nonunits in $\mathbb{F}_2$?